# Library Override loses position of instance

Tags: blend-files, linked-data

Use case: Link a collection from another file. Set resultant instance to arbitrary loc/rot/scale. Make Library Override.
Result: The objects that created from the override are positioned at the origin with zero rotation and 1:1 scale.

Summary:
When I use bpy.ops.object.make_override_library() on a linked collection instance, it immediately moves from where the instance was placed to the origin. Is there anyway to make it stay in place?

I've been trying to write a script to fix this, but I have lots of duplicate named objects (I'm making models with lots of identical elements). It's nigh-on impossible to associate the newly overridden object with its previous coordinates, as there seems to be no rhyme or reason as to the numerical suffixes that duplicate object and collection names are assigned. Furthermore, the afore mentioned operator does not provide any output as to *what* it actually did, so it's impossible to programmatically discover the objects that were created (or released?) by the library override!

Comment: iam not sure if you encounter is relatd to what  i have found - 
i asked at https://devtalk.blender.org/t/custom-properties-set-by-python-as-library-overrides-are-not-saved-in-file/20052

Comment: Did you found a solution for this? I get a similar issue and I can't solve it https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/258406/add-library-overrides-without-losing-all-existing-animations