# Add library overrides without losing all existing animations

Tags: linked-data, library-overrides

If I add a library overrides to a linked object that I animated before adding the library overrides, I lose all the animations (even the position is reset to zero). Is there a way to add the library overrides and still preserve somehow the created animations?

[image]

**EDIT**

I found a really **dirty** solution to solve that issue, by copying the animations on a dummy new object:

1. create a new dummy object (say a cube)
2. add to it at least one key frame for each property you want to record (e.g. location/rotation/scale): don't forget any or it will not be preserved later. I personally add them really far away in the timeline so that I can easily find them and delete them later.
3. select your main object you want to add override to
4. in the dope-sheet editor, select all its corresponding keyframes and copy them (`Ctrl-C`). Also, make sure to move the time bar at the position of the first key frame to paste them at the proper position.
5. select your dummy object, go in the dope-sheet editor, and paste (`Ctrl-V`) the keyframes.
6. make sure that all properties (location, scale…) have been properly copy/pasted (your cube should follow your main object)
7. add your library override on your main object: its position will be reset
8. do steps 2-6 again, except that the dummy object and main object are inverted (you are copying back on your main object the properties of your original object).
9. remove the dummy object
10. remove the initial dummy keyframe that you added at the very end of your object

I would be happy to find a better solution!

Comment: In the Dope Sheet editor select your armature, select *Action Editor* view, and if the action is empty use the drop down next to the New Action button to find your linked action and select.

Comment: @james_t I'm not sure to understand, in my case it's not an action that I want to animate but various stuff (bones position, shape keys…)